# Magento process returns and change order (Magento CE 1.8.1)

Tags: orders, sales, rma

we sometimes get returns (Yeah, only sometimes ;P)

and this is something I haven't been able to grasp: how do I process these returns and changes as simple as possible.

For instance:

- Can I return the product for another size? [same config product, different simple product based on size]
- Can I add a product?
- Can I return the product for a different product?

What we do now is: credit note the order. Then create new order by clicking create new order, new customer, enter all the data

Is there a faster way to handle the above situations?

Answer (score 1):

RMA is a Magento EE feature, therefore it is only basic implemented in magento.

This means, when you cancel an order, the products are readded to the stock if you want this.

But you can't do all the fancy stuff like change the order (size of a product). I'm not sure at the moment, but I think when the order is invoiced you are unable to change it? If this is the case I think your war is the right to go.

The alternative is to buy one of the many RMA (return merchandise authorization) modules or buy EE.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create new orders for RMAs. All returns and credit memos can be processed under the same (original) order. An RMA offers a list of "resolutions" that the customer or your admin can specify. How you follow up with that resolution is completely up to the admin, and it must be done by hand.

In other words, if an RMA is for a "refund", but refund does not automatically occur when you process and close the RMA; You must manually submit a credit memo and enter order comment as necessary. There is no simple solution for RMAs.